# Javascript only working in Chrome browser not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

So I have a table and I have to populate a modal using the data from the Table I have written following code

**Javascript**

```
 var tableHeaders = JSON.parse('["name","phone","email","message"]');
        console.log(tableHeaders) ;

$('.openUpdateform').on('click', function() {
  $('#callApi').hide();
  $('#updateData').show();
  tr = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();
  console.log(tr.children());
  for (var i = 1; i < tr.children().length - 1; i++) {
    j = i - 1;
    $('#' + tableHeaders[j]).val(tr.children()[i].outerText);
  }

  $('#data_row_id').val($(this).data('row_id'));
  $('#createWF').modal();
})
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/x6rf20fe/)

SO the above code works perfectly on Chrome but not in Mozilla Firefox any suggestions appreciated .

**Not Working**
Means from the Action DropDown if you select the `Edit Data` option it will open a popup and that popup gets filled in Chrome but not Firefox.

Thanks

Comment: I opened the jsfiddle in Firefox and it is working fine. Please describe **not working**

Comment: Can you define *not working*?

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: @Mr.Alien Kindly check my updated answer

Comment: @AlivetoDie Kindly check my updated ANswer

Comment: @Weedoze Answer Updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is that [Firefox doesn't support `Node.outerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/outerText). Use `Node.innerText` instead and you'll be all right.

Answer (score 3):

You must use "innerText" instead of "outerText".
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/outerText